# CodeIgniter 3 Routing Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I used CI's routes and have the following entry in config/routes.php

```
if($subdomain == 'debug')
{
    $route['debug/(:any)'] = "admin/debug/$1";
}
elseif($subdomain == 'dev')
{
    $route['models/(:any)'] = "v2/dev/models/$1";
}
```

If I were to browse to

```
dev.mydomain.com/models/test/
```

everything works fine and I get the correct output.

However, I were to browse to

```
dev.mydomain.com/models/test/trip_id/9091
```

I will get a 404 Error page.

Only way to make it to work is to use the following route entry.

```
$route['models/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)']       = "v2/dev/models/$1/$2/$3";
```

What really confuses me further is that it works if I were to browse to

```
debug.mydomain.com/debug/test/trip_id/9091
```

What am I missing here as the route entries looks similar but will only work on the first subdomain (debug.mydomain.com) but not on the latter (dev.mydomain.com)

This is the content of my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the `$config['base_url']` located inside `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: As we have multiple subdomains pointing to the same CI application, its relative to the URL. I don't think the issue is with this config.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['models/(:any)'] = "v2/dev/models/$1";
```

Check the route path if you are calling the controller from the folder
it should be yourfolder/controller/method_name/$1

Comment: The controller class is located at ../controllers/v2/dev/models.php

Comment: Try like below one

$route['models/(:any)'] = "v2/dev/models/method_name/$1";

If you are not calling the index() default.

Comment: Not really sure what you are telling me but as per the above route entry, v2 and dev are the directory name while models is the class file. If you are asking me to create one entry per method/function, I think its inpractical as I may have up to 30 methods/functions per class file.

Comment: In case I got it wrong, let me try to make it clearer. What I have in the entry is as follows: /folderName/folderName/className/$1, where $1 will be any method in the class file.

Comment: dev.mydomain.com/models/test/
Above url you have mentioned controller/test method.
call the method